# Load balancing Docker Registry v2 with HAProxy on Tutum

Tags: docker, haproxy, docker-registry

Did the following on Tutum:

#### Registry

1. Started a registry:2.1.1 service
2. Published the port 5000 and configured the registry service with:

   ```
   VIRTUAL_HOST=https://my-registry.my-host.net
   TCP_PORTS=5000/ssl
   SSL_CERT="..."
   ```
3. Now, pointed the my-registry.my-host.net DNS to the registry service endpoint and testing the registry with:

   ```
   docker login my-registry.my-host.net:5000
   ```

   Works just fine, including the SSL!

#### HAProxy

1. Started a tutum/haproxy:latest service, published the 443 port, added API access and linked to the registry service, everything else is default
2. Pointed my-registry.my-host.net DNS to the haproxy service endpoint and tested the registry login with:

   ```
   docker login my-registry.my-host.net
   ```

   This time, the request fails with:

   ```
   503 Service Unavailable
   No server is available to handle this request.
   ```

What am I missing?

Note: everything was done from Tutum's Dashboard web UI.

Additionally, here's the generated haproxy.cfg from the HAProxy service container, for those who have experience with HAProxy, but not necessarily with Tutum:

https://gist.github.com/lazabogdan/3bf52984faa092b1a50b (note: the registry service ID has been masked with XXXXXXXX and the real FQDN has been replaced with my-registry.my-host.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

I had to do the following:

1. Update the environment variable for the registry service from TCP_PORTS=5000/ssl to TCP_PORTS=5000
2. On the haproxy service, expose port 5000 on the container AND publish it on the host to port 443.
3. Now, I can successfully do:

   ```
   docker login my-registry.my-host.net
   ```